# Approximate a plane measurable set by disjoint squares

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset\mathbf{R}^2$ be a Lebesgue measurable set with positive measure, bounded or unbounded. For any given $a\in(0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$, I am wondering if there exist open squares $Q_1,Q_2\cdots$, finitely or countably many, such that $E$ can be approximated by $Q_i$'s in the following sense.

(1) $Q_i\cap Q_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. (2) $\mu(E\backslash (\cup Q_i))<\epsilon$. (3) $\mu(E\cap Q_i)\geq a\mu(Q_i)$ for every $i$. (Presumably $a$ is close to $1^-$.)

My thinking is the following. It is easy to cover $E$ by a slightly larger open set $U$: $E\subset U$, $\mu(E)\geq a\mu(U)$. By using net of squares, we can divide $U$ into disjoint, countably many half-open, half-closed squares $U_i$'s. The edges of the squares don't matter since they have measure zero. Now for $i=1,2,\cdots$, (i) if $\mu(E\cap U_i)\geq a\mu(U_i)$, then take it to be some $Q_j$ and this will reduce the measure of $E\backslash(\cup Q_j)$; (ii) otherwise, use a smaller open set to replace $U_i$ and continue this process. The question is, will the squares that we take eventually cover $E$ except on an arbitrarily small set?

Comment: I feel the answer is yes, but need to think of the details. The following may be relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem

Comment: @Mirko I found this https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-17771-7_6.pdf Can we just use the Vitali covering lemma on page 418?